# Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: jenkins, tfs, devops

I am fetching source code from TFS in Jenkins and getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified at AutomaticDBDeploy.Module1.Main()

What is the reason, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting that error message while synchronizing the source code, or while *building* the application?

Comment: @DanielMann while building the application

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio go to project menu and click on project properties under Platform target --> uncheck the Prefer-32-bit and Rebuild the solution and run the solution.

https://timxn.com/en/unhandled-exception-systemcomponentmodelwin32exception-system-cannot-find-file-specified